# FutureBuilder in Flutter - Calling API and using response for map marker

Tags: flutter, dart, maps, markers

I am calling an API and utilising the return Json data to post markers on a map

I have the Call returning a ListView fine on a separate application

I was receiving this error, before I had implemented the relevant FutureBuilder code in my map app

```
type 'Future<Stations>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
```

I then realised i hadn't implemented a Future Builder into the main constructor.

I tried to implement my Future builder from my other application calling the same HTTP, with some modifications.

I am now getting errors from the Future Builder construction after trying to implement a Future Builder, which I have been told will fix the previous error as it is mandatory, to the best of my beginners ability!

I am pulling the `stations.place.location.lat` & `stations.place.location.lng` Json to use in GeoCoordinates to place the marker

Here is the Dart code I am using, any guidance is appreciated. I will exclude code which is irrelevant to this issue.

The Future Builder (of which there is some rough code left in my example below) needs to go into my Main.dart

```
void main() {
  SdkContext.init(IsolateOrigin.main);

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget { 

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
 

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Stations> stations;
  


  @override
  void initState() {
    stations = API_Call().fetchStations(); 
   super.initState();
  }
    BuildContext _context;
  MapMarkerExample _mapMarkerExample; 
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _context = context;
    

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Example 1'),
        ),
        
      body:  Container(
        child: 

FutureBuilder<Stations>(
          future: API_Call().fetchStations(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {  
              var stations = snapshot.data.stations[index];
              
              
              Stack(
          children: [
            HereMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    button('Call', _anchoredMapMarkersButtonClicked),
                    button('Clear', _clearButtonClicked),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
        }
        );
        }
        }
        )
      )
      )
    );
  }
...
```

api_manager.dart

```
class MapMarkerExample{
 
    
 void showAnchoredMapMarkers() {
  var stations;
 
        stations = API_Call().fetchStations(); 
       for (Station stations in stations) {
           GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = GeoCoordinates (stations.place.location.lat, stations.place.location.lng);
         
           }

           GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = stations.coordinates;
           _addPOIMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
 
    }
...
```

api_call.dart

```
class API_Call {
  
Future<Stations> fetchStations() async {
    var client = http.Client();

      final response = await client.get(
      'https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?in=x,-x&return=transport&apiKey=MY_API_KEY');
   
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Stations.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)); 
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load stations');
  }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your immediate syntax problem, you forgot an `await`:

```
stations = await API_Call().fetchStations();
```

However, that has a ripple effect through your code, since now the function needs to be `async` and probably needs to be awaited elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to implement and its throwing up issues all over the place. Is the async on the http call not the only one required?

Comment: No, indeed, async is "infectious", a function having an async call in it with await has itself to be async.

Comment: Have read into it and understand it all better now! Do you have any tips for how to arrange my FutureBuilder<Stations> on main.dart as its returning null?